# How to access mongodb variables from nodejs cartridge on OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, environment-variables, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am trying to deploy an application prototype to openshift. It works locally with mongodb at 127.0.0.1. I am trying to get it to respect `process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL` when in the openshift environment but that variable is not accessible to my nodejs cartridge at runtime.

I can see that it is being set in my application's shell environment. When I do `rhc ssh` and then `export` I see `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL=[full_url_with_password]` and it all looks good.

But when, in my node.js application, I call `process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL` it returns `undefined`.

To double check, I did a `console.log(util.inspect(process.env))` from within my node.js app, and what I saw was different from what I see within my appication's secure shell. No OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_* variables were in the environment that is exposed to my node.js app.

How can I access variables across different cartridges? Or is this a configuration error?

Comment: It appears it may have been an issue with the order in which the cartridges are started? After some stopping and starting of the app/cartridges the problem went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a configuration error.  I have a similar application and

```
console.log(util.inspect(process.env))
```

gives me a clear picture of the mongodb environment variables.

The [developers page](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html) indicates that:

> Database environment variables pertain to a database, if one exists, and are used to connect an application to a database. Note that these connections are only available to an application internally; you cannot connect from an external source.

This suggests, to me, that the nodejs is external to the mongodb installation.  I have an idea that it can be verified with the command:

```
rhc app show OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME
```

It might lead to the source of the problem. A correctly configured app would have nodejs and mongodb in this list.